# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-meteor, angular-router

I am using Meteor with Angular.
Somehow, it always gives me the error whenever i tried to put the *Router* dependency in the component's constructor.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

while removing the *Router* parameter works just fine!

```
constructor() {}
```

I am trying to navigate from one component to another component using this.router.navigate() in the component ts.

This is the error i got:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?).

Still new to angular, been trying to solve this for days! Appreciate if you can help this poor soul out!

**HomeComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-component',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

}
```

**AppModule**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../components/login/login.component';

import { MainPage } from '../pages/main/main';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    MainPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../components/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: '/home', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
},
{ 
    path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent 
},
{ 
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent 
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes 
{ enableTracing: false } // <-- debugging purposes only
)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
"@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"air-datepicker": "^2.2.3",
"babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
"bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
"jarallax": "^1.9.3",
"jquery": "2.2.4",
"meteor-node-stubs": "^0.3.2",
"meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.8",
"moment": "^2.20.1",
"ngx-cookie": "^2.0.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"stripe": "^5.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},

"devDependencies": {
"@types/meteor": "^1.4.12",
"@types/meteor-accounts-phone": "0.0.5",
"@types/underscore": "^1.8.6",
"meteor-typings": "^1.4.1",
"typescript": "^2.6.2"
}
```

Comment: This error usually happens from circular dependencies, but since you are importing from `@angular/router` it is a strange error to be getting...have you tried removing `node_modules` directory and doing an `npm install` again just to see if there was any issues with some corrupt modules?

Comment: @Lansana Hey, thanks for the advice! I tried and the same error is still there. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What happens if you add a `declare const Router: any;` to the top of your `HomeComponent`, and remove the `@angular/router` import? I suspect that something else may be importing that already, thus creating the circular import issue. I'm not sure if Meteor has any involvement with this error, but I imagine it does because you would never get that error with just Angular. Try that and let me know what happens.

Comment: @Lansana Just tried, same error :/ I am running with Meteor CLI, do you think it can be caused by the incorrect use of file structure?

Comment: If you want a quick fix (since you've been stuck on this for days), you can change `private router: Router` to `@Inject(forwardRef(() => Router)) router: Router`, and that will use the instance that's already injected elsewhere (docs: https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef). But I would not recommend this, you should try to get to the root of the problem. This is just a last resort.

Comment: Have you read this guide? https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/setup

Comment: @Lansana Kraken mentioned too. I am probably gonna have to hunt down where this circular dependency issue is..

Comment: @Lansana yes i've read through that guide. i am not using the angular-meteor package.. so i might be doing something wrong somewhere......

Comment: If the recommended approach for Meteor+Angular is to use the angular-meteor package, I would strongly advise using that approach then. Trying to plug them in together yourself may be desirable if you know exactly what you're doing, but it can create situations such as yours with incorrect setups resulting in undesirable errors that are hard to find and fix. Another approach you might want to take is looking at a starter project on GitHub with someone using Meteor+Angular separately, and see how they're doing things/what you're doing that's different.

Comment: @Lasana Yes, i guess u are right, was too spontaneous at getting it plugging all frameworks together! Thanks for the tips (:

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I don't see any problem in your code except a missing `,` in the forRoot call args. Can that be it? Would be weird indeed - if that isn't just a mistake in pasting your code here, by any sense you should have a compiler error instead, and your IDE crying warnings.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes // , missing here
{ enableTracing: false }
)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Comment: @funkizer hey thanks for pointing that out! The same error still comes out though.

Answer (score 0):

Strange stuff, but 1 thing that you can try is to inject router explicitly

```
constructor(@Inject(Router) private router) {
    // use `this.router` which is the router provider
  }
```

if it solve this problem you may have circular dependency somewhere else.

Comment: yes! now we know its a circular dependency issue. It works when this is added.

Comment: my way is completly right for any purpose, you can use it for now. And i sad that you may have this problem) actually this stuff with @Inject are more verbose but more relyable.

Comment: great! so is it a "recommended" way to use the @inject?

Comment: actually this is this is really funny stuff, because they are same under the hood, we are using `private router: Router`  just for our  easement. You know) you are free to use it